# Computing the area of a subset of unit sphere

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Let $(x,y,f(x))\in \mathbb{S}^2$ where $f$ is a given smooth function and $\mathbb{S}^2$ is the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with center at the origin. How to find out the area of the following surface?
$$\Sigma:=\{(x,y,f(x)): (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\} \cap \mathbb{S}^2$$

My attempt is to first look at some special cases. Say $f(x)=x$, then the surface is exactly
$$\Sigma:=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: 2x^2+y^2=1 \},$$which is an ellipse with area $\pi/\sqrt{2}$. In general, is there a formula?

Comment: You have given the projection of $\Sigma$ into the plane. This is not the region in the sphere!

Comment: Do you mean to intersect with the unit ball $B^3\subset\Bbb R^3$, rather than the unit sphere? The intersection of the graph of $f$ with the sphere will be a curve, not a surface.

Comment: @TedShifrin, thanks. What I what to ask is how to find the area of $\Sigma$, where $\Sigma$ is defined as in the post. I think $\Sigma$ is a surface, but I don't know how to find the area of $\Sigma$. And I mean the subset of unit sphere.

Comment: Then it will not be *area*. The intersection of a surface with the sphere will be a curve.